# Eclipse Android: Multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, eclipse

I wanted to adapt my app to different Screen sizes.
So I created four different layout sizes: small, normal, large and xlarge.

But that doesn't work for every device.

Because on some devices it doesn't look right.
Because there are a lot of smartphones and tablets with more than only four different sizes.

So I have to create layouts for every single device.

Is that right?
How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
If this does not work for you, then you can try using the actual size of the device with the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    final float width = dm.widthPixels;
    final float height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Then resize your layouts to match these sizes.